# JIBX : Error in the JiBX code

Tags: java, jibx

Project Set Up:

Project Domains contains all domain Object with No jibx configuration.

```
Class A {
  List<A> list;
}
```

Project JibxTest contains jibx configuration and its contains Domains.jar

When we try configured the binding.xml in Project JibxTest as following:

```
<binding>
    <mapping name="A" class="Domains.A" ordered="false">
          <collection item-type="Domains.A" field="list" usage="optional" create- type="java.util.ArrayList"/> 
    </mapping>
</binding>
```

we are getting JIBX exception :

```
Error during code generation for file 'C:\JIBXTest/binding.xml' -
     [bind]  this may be due to an error in your binding or classpath, or to an error in the JiBX code ***
     [bind] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal error - cannot modify class Domains.A loaded from C:\JIBXTest\lib\Domains.jar
```

When we copy the Domain.A class in to JibxTest project and modify the binding file.
It works.

Answer (score -5):

Per [this email](http://osdir.com/ml/java-jibx-users/2010-06/msg00016.html):

> JiBX should be able to work with the classes in the jar as long as 
>   you're only using public fields or methods. If the fields aren't public, 
>   you need to either switch to public get/set methods (if available) or 
>   unjar the class files so that the JiBX binding compiler can modify them.

In Java it is standard to have getters and setters, so I suggest you add those.

Comment: issue is the when Class A have instance of List<A> and we are trying to read it from the jar

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. If you want my help you will have to be more clear.

Comment: thanks Robin Green, But issue is resolved now . When we used the get-method and set-method instead of using "field"

Comment: If you are wondering why you might be receiving downvotes on this answer - the since deleted comments are a subject of a meta post -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204719/is-reputation-the-currency-of-stackoverflow